# click() and enter should trigger the function

Tags: jquery, ajax

My question might sound a bit stupid but i need to know if you can have click() and keypress function for the same button. For example here is my code:

```
 $("#Submit").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var th = '<tr><th>' + "Business" +'</th><th>' + "Address"+       '</th><th>'+ "Rating" + '</th><th>' + "Date" + '</th></tr>';
            $("#restaurants").empty().html(th);
            var Searching = $("#Search").val();
            $.ajax({
             type : "GET",
             url : "http://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/lb514/hygiene/hygiene.php",
             dataType : "json",
             data : {op : "searchname", name : Searching},
             success : function(data){
              if(data.length < 1 ){
                $("#restaurants").empty().html(th);
                var response = confirm(" This search term : " + Searching + " was not found in our database. Please try another search ");
                 if(response){ 
                  $('#Search').val("");
                 }
                $("#restaurants").html(th);
              }else if(data.length > 1){
                $.each(data,function(key,results){
                 $("#restaurants").append(
                             "<tr><td>" + results.business +"</td>"+
                             "<td>" + results.address + "</td>" + 
                             "<td>" + results.rating + "</td>" + 
                             "<td>" + results.date + "</td></tr>")
                  })
                   $('#Search').val("");
                }
              }
            });
          })
```

This function currently is only triggered with clicking on the "Submit button". If i press the enter button after filling out the search text it does not work. So is there a way to make a function trigger with both click and enter?

Comment: I assume the Search button is in a form, so you are probably looking for [`$('#form').submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) instead of `$('#button').click()`

Answer (score 1):

You could bind a button click on the back of the user pressing the enter key when focused on the search text.  It would work as follows:

```
$('#Search').keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        $("#Submit").click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#Search').keyup(function(e){

    var e = event || window.event; // for modern browser and IE

    if(e.keyCode == 13){       // charCode for enter key      
        $("#Submit").click(); // when it is checked, then triggers the submit btn
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.input').keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    $('form#login').submit();
    return false;
  }
});
```